# How do I make the LeftAndRight activity in Jeremy sliding menu Example to become my Main page?

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I have a problem here. I can't make the LeftAndRight activity as my Main activity on Ecplise by using the ExampleListActivity in Jeremy library. https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu

When i run the application it gives me an error. But i wanted to start the LeftAndRightActivity.java at the first page how do i do that?

I have designed the action bar and the sliding just like him with a baseactivity, leftandrightactivity and samplelistfragment.java files. Then in my main.java

```
     public class MainActivity extends SherlockPreferenceActivity {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setTitle(R.string.app_name);

    Class<?> cls = null;
    cls = LeftAndRightActivity.class;
Intent intent = new Intent(this, cls);
startActivity(intent);

}
```

BaseActivity.java

```
    public class BaseActivity extends SlidingFragmentActivity {
SlidingMenu menu;
private int mTitleRes;
protected ListFragment mFrag;

public BaseActivity(int titleRes) {
    mTitleRes = titleRes;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setTitle(mTitleRes);

    // set the Behind View
    setBehindContentView(R.layout.menu_frame);
    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        FragmentTransaction t = this.getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        mFrag = new SampleListFragment();
        t.replace(R.id.menu_frame, mFrag);
        t.commit();
    } else {
        mFrag = (ListFragment)this.getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.menu_frame);
    }

    // customize the SlidingMenu
    SlidingMenu sm = getSlidingMenu();
    sm.setShadowWidthRes(R.dimen.shadow_width);
    sm.setShadowDrawable(R.drawable.shadow);
    sm.setBehindOffsetRes(R.dimen.slidingmenu_offset);
    sm.setFadeDegree(0.35f);
    sm.setTouchModeAbove(SlidingMenu.TOUCHMODE_FULLSCREEN);

    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setIcon(android.R.color.transparent);
    getSupportActionBar().setTitle("");
       BitmapDrawable bg = (BitmapDrawable)getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.background);
       getSupportActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(bg);


}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case android.R.id.home:
        toggle();
        return true;
    case R.id.github:
        showSecondaryMenu();
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getSupportMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}
  }
```

LeftAndRightAcitivity.java

```
  public class LeftAndRightActivity extends BaseActivity {

public LeftAndRightActivity() {
    super(R.string.left_and_right);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    getSlidingMenu().setMode(SlidingMenu.LEFT_RIGHT);
    getSlidingMenu().setTouchModeAbove(SlidingMenu.TOUCHMODE_FULLSCREEN);

    setContentView(R.layout.content_frame);
    getSupportFragmentManager()
    .beginTransaction()
    .replace(R.id.content_frame, new SampleListFragment())
    .commit();

    getSlidingMenu().setSecondaryMenu(R.layout.menu_frame_two);
    getSlidingMenu().setSecondaryShadowDrawable(R.drawable.shadowright);
    getSupportFragmentManager()
    .beginTransaction()
    .replace(R.id.menu_frame_two, new SampleListFragment())
    .commit();
}

  }
```

SampleListFragment.java

```
public class SampleListFragment extends ListFragment {

public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.list, null);
}

public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    SampleAdapter adapter = new SampleAdapter(getActivity());
    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
        adapter.add(new SampleItem("Sample List", android.R.drawable.ic_menu_search));
    }
    setListAdapter(adapter);
}

private class SampleItem {
    public String tag;
    public int iconRes;
    public SampleItem(String tag, int iconRes) {
        this.tag = tag; 
        this.iconRes = iconRes;
    }
}

public class SampleAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<SampleItem> {

    public SampleAdapter(Context context) {
        super(context, 0);
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.row, null);
        }
        ImageView icon = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.row_icon);
        icon.setImageResource(getItem(position).iconRes);
        TextView title = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.row_title);
        title.setText(getItem(position).tag);

        return convertView;
    }

}
 }
```

or did I do anything wrong? Appreciate with any help . Thanks

This is the changes i have made but it still won't launch at first page

on my mainactivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends BaseActivity {

public MainActivity(int titleRes) {
    super(titleRes);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    getSlidingMenu().setMode(SlidingMenu.LEFT_RIGHT);
    getSlidingMenu().setTouchModeAbove(SlidingMenu.TOUCHMODE_FULLSCREEN);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    getSupportFragmentManager()
    .beginTransaction()
    .replace(R.id.content_frame, new LeftListFragment())
    .commit();

    getSlidingMenu().setSecondaryMenu(R.layout.menu_frame_two);
    getSlidingMenu().setSecondaryShadowDrawable(R.drawable.shadowright);
    getSupportFragmentManager()
    .beginTransaction()
    .replace(R.id.menu_frame_two, new RightListFragment())
    .commit();
}

}
```

Comment: You want to have left and right sliding menu in launching the app itself ? i.e lets say when you launch app you will have a view and if u drag from left, left sliding menu should open and similarly right sliding menu for sliding from right. i'm i correct?

Comment: Yes you are correct I wanted that interface but I have no idea how to do it. I have tried using intent to the page but it doesn't work

Comment: And also i tried putting the left and right as my main activity but it can't extends base activity so i am kind of lost right now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

analyse the sample example properly. Here is short description, simply create 2 fragments with different layouts. then use the API like below to set them as left and right menu

```
    getSlidingMenu().setMode(SlidingMenu.LEFT_RIGHT);
    getSlidingMenu().setTouchModeAbove(SlidingMenu.TOUCHMODE_FULLSCREEN);

    setBehindContentView(R.layout.menu_frame);

    FragmentTransaction t = this.getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                mFrag = new SampleListFragment();
                t.replace(R.id.menu_frame, mFrag);
                t.commit(); //left menu

getSlidingMenu().setSecondaryMenu(R.layout.right_menu_layout);
        getSlidingMenu().setSecondaryShadowDrawable(R.drawable.shadowright);
        getSupportFragmentManager()
        .beginTransaction()
        .replace(R.id.right_list, new RightListFragment())
        .commit(); //right menu
```

use `setcontentview` to set your main view

But make sure you extend with `BaseActivity` else it wont work.

Comment: Please look at my edited Main, it's still not working