# how to have left and right sliding menu in launching the app itself using jfeinstein10 library?

Tags: android

In jeremy library https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu in his example he have a leftandright.java. But when the app is launched, you will have to choose left and right to go to it. Any idea how I could actually making it launch with the left and right menu on the first page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your need,you can set layoutParams.rightMargin or layoutParams.leftMargin

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19557679/how-do-i-make-the-leftandright-activity-in-jeremy-sliding-menu-example-to-become  could u take a look at this thankss